# How to use re match objects in a list comprehension

Tags: python, regex, list-comprehension

I have a function to pick out lumps from a list of strings and return them as another list:

```
def filterPick(lines,regex):
    result = []
    for l in lines:
        match = re.search(regex,l)
        if match:
            result += [match.group(1)]
    return result
```

Is there a way to reformulate this as a list comprehension? Obviously it's fairly clear as is; just curious.

---

Thanks to those who contributed, special mention for @Alex. Here's a condensed version of what I ended up with; the regex match method is passed to filterPick as a "pre-hoisted" parameter:

```
import re

def filterPick(list,filter):
    return [ ( l, m.group(1) ) for l in list for m in (filter(l),) if m]

theList = ["foo", "bar", "baz", "qurx", "bother"]
searchRegex = re.compile('(a|r$)').search
x = filterPick(theList,searchRegex)

>> [('bar', 'a'), ('baz', 'a'), ('bother', 'r')]
```

Answer (score 79, accepted):

```
[m.group(1) for l in lines for m in [regex.search(l)] if m]
```

The "trick" is the `for m in [regex.search(l)]` part -- that's how you "assign" a value that you need to use more than once, within a list comprehension -- add just such a clause, where the object "iterates" over a single-item list containing the one value you want to "assign" to it.  Some consider this stylistically dubious, but I find it practical sometimes.

Comment: Alex, I like that; thanks and +1. I have some fairly heavy lifting to do with this code - should I worry about the extra overhead of setting-up and tearing-down the "faux iterator"? BTW I subscribe to the doctrine of "optimise later".

Comment: @Brent, the "faux iterator" should be negligible wrt the search call; one minor optimization is to use `(regex.search(l),)` in lieu of `[regex.search(l)]` (which I find more readable but is minutely slower -- I thought you couldn't possibly be in a hurry as you were actually calling the `re.search` function from the module rather than the re object's method.  Pulling `regex.search` as a bound method outside of the listcomp is another minor but useful optimization, btw.

Comment: as soon as I saw your answer I realised that using re.search was not the best way to go. Could you clarify for me how you would "[pull the] regex.search as a bound method outside of the listcomp"? I really appreciate your patience with a listcomp and Python noob.

Comment: @Brent, `src=regex.search; lst=[m.group(1) for l in lines for m in [src(l)] if m]` is the "bound method hoisting" optimization (does the method lookup once instead of redoing it for each line -- Python doesn't hoist attribute lookups for you, when you need such optimization you can however do it manually, as I just showed).

Comment: @AlexMartelli, I find a nested comprehension more readable than the "double for hack": `search = re.compile('...').search; out = [m.group(1) for m in map(search, lines) if m]` You could use nested brackets, but in this case a map() is just as readable, since the transformer is a simple callable, and it's actually faster! (33% faster than for hack with a tuple, **40% faster than for hack with a list**, and 15% faster than a nested list comprehension using brackets.) Measured using a moderately complex regexp `'(a.*b.*c)'`, which is O(n²), on a huge list of file names.

Comment: @AlexMartelli - this is a good candidate to rewrite using ':=' operator - it is 2021!

Answer (score 12):

```
return [m.group(1) for m in (re.search(regex, l) for l in lines) if m]
```

Answer (score 7):

It could be shortened a little

```
def filterPick(lines, regex):
    matches = map(re.compile(regex).match, lines)
    return [m.group(1) for m in matches if m]
```

You could put it all in one line, but that would mean you would have to match every line twice which would be a bit less efficient.

Comment: Nah, no need to match each line twice, see my answer.

Comment: Indeed, your answer is much cleaner, +1 from me :)

Answer (score 5):

Starting `Python 3.8`, and the introduction of [assignment expressions (PEP 572)](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/) (`:=` operator), it's possible to use a local variable within a list comprehension in order to avoid calling multiple times the same expression:

```
# items = ["foo", "bar", "baz", "qurx", "bother"]
[(x, match.group(1)) for x in items if (match := re.compile('(a|r$)').search(x))]
# [('bar', 'a'), ('baz', 'a'), ('bother', 'r')]
```

This:

- Names the evaluation of `re.compile('(a|r$)').search(x)` as a variable `match` (which is either `None` or a `Match` object)
- Uses this `match` named expression in place (either `None` or a `Match`) to filter out non matching elements
- And re-uses `match` in the mapped value by extracting the first group (`match.group(1)`).

Answer (score -15):

```
>>> "a" in "a visit to the dentist" 
True 
>>> "a" not in "a visit to the dentist" 
False
```

That also works with a search query you're hunting down in a list

`P='a', 'b', 'c'

'b' in P` returns true

Comment: How does that answer the question?

Comment: This questions may present a better way to check for inputs into an list than re, but by the way don't work if you wan't to grep results. U can always do a simple loop for around the re output. Is not much difference to do it manually than use a function that does the same...