# What is the best way to sort list with custom sorting parameters in Python?

Tags: python, list, sorting

I have a series of lists that looks like this:

```
li1 = ['a.1', 'b.9', 'c.8', 'd.1', 'e.2']
li2 = ['a.4', 'b.1', 'c.2', 'd.2', 'e.4']
```

How can I rearrange the items in each list so that the first item is 'b.something'? For the example above:

```
li1 = ['b.9', 'a.1', 'c.8', 'd.1', 'e.2']
li2 = ['b.1', 'a.4', 'c.2', 'd.2', 'e.4']
```

Maintaining the order after the first item isn't important. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I'm not sure, but this question might be of interest to you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2436607/how-to-use-re-match-objects-in-a-list-comprehension

Comment: just wondering why everybody used `s.startwith('b')`, instead of `s[0] == 'b'`.  is there any performance advantage?  if not i want to save my brain's long-term memory use.

Comment: @yosukesabai: Only one answer uses `s.startwith('b')`. The others use `s.startwith('b.')` like was asked for in the question.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams: sorry, then, what i meant to say is `s.startwith('b.')` vs `s[:2] == 'b.'`.  is the first superior to the second, and if so in which sense?

Comment: @yosukesabai: Well, for single elements, `startswith` doesn't crash on empty strings. For multiple characters, I don't see any advantage apart from reading nicer (well, you can specify start/stop and alternatives, but that's not needed here).

Comment: There is an advantage in `startswith`, which is not to take care about the number of characters to slice from the string (and therefore to avoid dumb index errors).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> rearrange the items in each list so that the first item is 'b.something'
>
> Maintaining the order after the first item isn't important.

That isn't sorting, then. Conceptually, you're just trying to bring that element to the front.

In other words, you want a list that consists of that element, followed by everything that isn't that element. Fudging this a little for the case where there are multiple `b.something`s, and noting that we don't care what happens as long as the first element is a `b.something`, we can rephrase that: a list of every element meeting the condition ("starts with `b.`"), followed by every element not meeting the condition. (This is sometimes called *partitioning*; see for example `std::partition` in C++.)

In Python, this is as simple as describing those two list-components with list comprehensions and sticking them together:

```
[x for x in li if x.startswith('b.')] + [x for x in li if not x.startswith('b.')]
```

...Or you can pretend that you're sorting, just with a bunch of elements that really only have two values after the `key` is applied, and apply the appropriate `key`, as in Ignacio Vasquez-Abrams' answer.

Comment: That's the closest to the request. I don't know how fast it could be regarding to `sort` anyway, as you have to read the list twice with same function for filtering.

Comment: wow, this is cool. for some reason joining list comprehensions together never occurred to me. thanks.

Comment: @Joël reading the list twice only causes constant-factor overhead. Sorting is O(n lg n), since `sort` needs to be able to sort arbitrarily and thus must do some kind of comparison-based sort, while each filtering list-comprehension pass is trivially seen to be O(n).

Comment: [Python sorting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timsort) is O(n lg n) in the worst case; on "mostly sorted" data such as this (elements that result in the same key are already sorted since Python's sorting is stable), complexity approaches O(n).

Answer (score 5):

Python's sorting is stable, so you will maintain the order after the first item regardless.

```
li1.sort(key=lambda x: not x.startswith('b.'))
```

Comment: This is very slick, but I imagine that some would argue that "explicit is better than implicit" means you shouldn't treat booleans as comparable values (`False < True`), and thus would expand to something like `0 if x.startswith('b.') else 1`. I'm not one of those people, though. :)

Answer (score 3):

You can use `sorted`, that accepts a `key` argument, and returns a list:

```
>>> li1 = ['a.1', 'b.2', 'c.8']
>>> def k(s):
...     if s.startswith('b.'):
...         return 1
...     else:
...         return 2
...
>>> sorted(li1, key=k)
['b.2', 'a.1', 'c.8']
```

`k` shall return something that can be compared between iterable items.

Note: `sort` change the input in-place and returns nothing, when `sorted` returns the sorted list and does not modify your list. Both work the same way.